# How to reduce font size in savefig code in pandas

Tags: pandas, plot, heatmap, correlation, font-size

I have created a correlation matrix in pandas using this code:

```
corr=data.corr()
```

I have then saved the correlation heatmap with this code

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 6))
mask = np.triu(np.ones_like(data.corr(), dtype=np.bool))
heatmap = sns.heatmap(data.corr(), mask=mask, vmin=-1, vmax=1, annot=True, cmap='BrBG')
heatmap.set_title('Correlation Heatmap', fontdict={'fontsize':18}, pad=16);

plt.savefig(dataQualityCheck+'correlationHeatmap.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight', font = {'family' : 'normal', 'weight' : 'bold', 'size' : 8})
```

The heatmap looks like this:

[image]

How can I modify (reduce, actually) the font size of the numbers inside the heatmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, there is the parameter `annot_kws` that you can pass to `sns.heatmap` and define the size in:

```
heatmap = sns.heatmap(data.corr(), mask=mask, vmin=-1, vmax=1, annot=True, cmap='BrBG', 
                      annot_kws={'size':5}) # replace 5 by any value as needed
```